# Retrieve TBW / Total LBA Written using RAID 0

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, smart

I have two SSDs ( `WDS500G1B0A-00H9H0` ) in RAID 0 and I want to know how many terabytes have been written on them so far.
However, the `Total_LBAs_Written` attribute gives me an incorrect value ( < 50'000 ).

I searched for a solution and tried `DiskSmartView` and `HDD Guardian` so far, but both failed to give me a plausible value, so I assumed the difficulties are based on the RAID configuration, but I could not find any solution. Any ideas?

---

### Edit (08/05/21):

I had a look into my BIOS and it would appear that stupid past me disabled S.M.A.R.T.

So, I'd assume that this is the reason for the `Total_LBSa_Written` attribute being incorrect, but why do attributes like the `Power_On_Hours` and `Power_Cycle_Count` then show reasonable values? Are they not affected by the BIOS setting?

Also, some more information (that I should've probably added from the beginning):

**S.M.A.R.T output:**

https://www.diffchecker.com/k7YWqhDc

**Disk Management:**

[image: Disk Management]

Comment: I think @DanielB meant this https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=279&lang=en

Comment: Or try a newer version of smartmontools. There's a chance that the unit for the value is G(i)B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S.M.A.R.T. was never really standardized and therefore, the definitions of the attribute IDs are pretty much entirely up to the vendor of a specific drive.

For accurate "interpretations" of the data, it's best to use the utility provided by the vendor, namely the `Western Digital Dashboard` in your case. (Some vendors might provide datasheet that includes the definitions.)

Looks like the field in concern is in the unit of G(i?)B instead of logical block.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)
defines these values, but does not define their meaning:

[image]

The early idea was for "Total_LBAs_*" fields to be counted in disk sectors
and be 48-bits large (compared with 32-bits fro all other fields),
which at the time were 512 bytes long, as documented by
[Samsung](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310051031/http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/whitepaper/whitepaper07.html):

> **ID # 241 Total LBAs Written**
>
> Represents the total size of all LBAs (Logical Block Address) required
> for all of the write requests sent to the SSD from the OS. To
> calculate the total size (in Bytes), multiply the raw value of this
> attribute by 512B.

However, modern big disks have nixed that first number, and from then on the
standards seem to be undefined.

I have found an Intel Application Note from 2017:
[Intel Solid State Drive Data Center for SATA - SMART Attributes](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/solid-state-drives/Intel_SSD_Smart_Attrib_for_SATA.PDF)
in which I have found this text:

[image]

So what we have is that one very influential manufacturer has defined
the LBA size as 32MB.

I do not know if this was accepted by other manufacturers, but using it for
your `Total_LBSa_Written` value of 49217, this is calculated as:

```
14848 * 32 MB / 1024 = 464 GB
```

It's up to you to judge if this value seems logical for the disk in question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it seems like WD has changed the attribute to `Total GB Write`, tho, which is 15GB per disk and makes a lot more sense. :)

Comment: `Total_LBAs_Written is 14848 and 14857` He meant 15TB, I suppose. And if you are interested to see how vendor-specifc they are, see https://github.com/smartmontools/smartmontools/blob/RELEASE_7_2/smartmontools/drivedb.h#L4448 (And as I anchored, if @FatalBulletHit had used the latest version of smartmontools, this question might have never been raised.)

Comment: @TomYan: Your link doesn't mention LBA size. Anyway, for a 500 GB disk to write 15 TB means it was fully written 30 times. The disk power-on hours is 16493, which makes 687 days or only 1.8 years. This seems an excessive usage for a small USB disk. According to my calculations the disk would have been written 3 times only. It's up to the user to say what kind of usage he was doing of the disk.

Comment: @harrymc You accidentally copied the `Total_LBAs_Read` value and I meant 15 TB per drive - which may seem like a lot, but I feared far worse considering I own the drives for 4 years now and have been extracting game audio files on it various time for data analysis reasons (makes my incompetence sound a lot more professional). And all the games on it get regularly updated, too, so with a life expectancy of 200 TBW, I'm quite happy. Also, they're SATA drives, not USB drives.

Comment: Right, I corrected my arithmetic. 15 TB still seems like a lot, since this would make about 1 GB written for each hour that the disk was powered on and more than 3 GB read, but you are the only judge of its feasibility.

Comment: @TomYan I just tried smartmontools and, indeed, it showed the attribute name correctly. I just assumed them to be standardized and expected sector sizes of 512 of 4096 Bytes, which would'nt've made any sense.

Comment: @harrymc I extracted/converted the better of a TB during the past week, that's ~3GB/h per drive - definitely not the healthiest thing for a SSD but also significantly faster than doing it on my HDD. You made those 15TB in 4 years sound a lot worse with 1GB/h, tho, hopefully, I'll be done with torturing my SSD rather sooner than later. Either way, I'm more worried about my 960 EVO with apparently 31.3TB written and 100 TBW... ._.